# C++. Почему выводит адреса в памяти, а не значения переменных?

Tags: c, c++

Всем привет!

Разбираюсь с указателями, не могу понять, почему при выводе матрицы и в первом и втором случае выводятся адреса (помечено комментарием)? Как правильно вывести адрес и как правильно само значение? Заранее спасибо)

```
#include <iostream>
void main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    int i, j,
        n = 3, // строки
        m = 3; // столбцы
    float b[100][100];

    // Создаем матрицу
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<m;j++) {
            printf("Введите элемент [%i,%i]: ", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%d", b+i+j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Выводим матрицу
    printf("----------------------------\n");
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<m;j++) {
            printf("%d\t", b+i+j); // 1
            printf("%d\t", *(b+i+j)); // 2
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("----------------------------\n");

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: А у меня вопрос: раз уж размер строк и столбцов явно задан, то почему бы не выбрать массив массивов по меньше, к примеру b[10][10]?

Answer (score 2):

Сколько ошибок в таком маленьком коде...

```
#include <iostream>
```

а дальше весь код на чистом си. Какой смысл - никакого. Добавляем

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

и пишем все на чистом си.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
```

это исключительно для старых систем. На нормальных OS это не нужно.

```
float b[100][100];
```

запомним - двумерный массив **вещественных чисел**.

```
scanf("%d", b+i+j);
```

а здесь сходу сразу минимум две ошибки (а то и все три).

Первое - раз сказали, что массив вещественных чисел, почему вводим целое? scanf наивный и вводит так как сказали. Какой будет результат - неведомо.

Второе - адресация массива. Так как массив размером 100 на 100, то индексы девяти элементов должны быть 0,1,2,100,101,102,200,201,202. А по этой формуле выходит 0, 4, 8, 4, 8, 12, 8, 12, 16.  Но я сознательно сделал умолчал об одном. В первом случае это индексы в массиве. А массив имеет тип вещественного (у Вас). А это скорее всего 4 (а может и 6 или 8) байт. А во втором случае это просто адреса. Переформулирую. Если привести все к адресам в байтах, то для массива **целых 4 байтовых** адреса будут такими:

```
0, 4, 8, 400, 404, 408, 800, 804, 808
```

Поэтому, так как вводим непонятно что, то и вывод обсуждать не имеет смысла.

Итак, мой вариант

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int i, j,
        n = 3, // строки
        m = 3; // столбцы
    int b[100][100];

    // Создаем матрицу
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<m;j++) {
            printf("Введите элемент [%i,%i]: ", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%d", &b[i][j]); //явная, нормальная адресация
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Выводим матрицу
    printf("----------------------------\n");
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<m;j++) {
            printf("%d\t", b[i][j]); // 1
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("----------------------------\n");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, что разобрали ошибки :) Но конкретно если по задаче, то ваш вариант не подходит. Я так делал раньше, а сейчас нужно с указателями...

Comment: я тут сам у себя нашел ошибки. Когда пишете b+1, то так как это работа с указателями, то 1 превращается в размер массива, то есть в 400. Даже веселее, чем я думал с самого начала. Лучше используйте указатель более явно.

Comment: @inferus-vv, а более конкретно: почему не подходить данный вариант?

Answer (score 1):

b — массив массивов на float, или указатель на указатель float'ов. Поэтому b+i+j — это указатель на указатель float'ов. Правильнее писать *(b+i)+j.

Кроме того, формат %d предназначен для парсинга целых десятичных, а не float. Нужно использовать f, e, g или a, а не %d. Указатель выводится как %p.

Чтение

```
scanf("%g", *(b+i)+j);
```

Печать

```
printf("%p\t", *(b+i)+j); // 1
printf("%g\t", *(*(b+i)+j)); // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

[[@inferus-vv](/users/6278/inferus-vv)](/users/6278/inferus-vv), для обращения к `b[i][j]` в той форме, как Вы хотите, пишите такие выражения:

```
b + i * 100 + j    // адрес i,j-го элемента матрицы
*(b + i * 100 + j) // значение этого элемента
```

100 -- это *количество столбцов* (элементов) в каждой строке Вашей матрицы.

Естественно, это относится к "нормальной" (традиционной) матрице, все элементы которой находятся в последовательных ячейках памяти, а не к "матрице", конструируемой вот таким (весьма распространенным) способом (как Вам описал [[@Дож](/users/865/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6)](/users/865/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6)):

```
float **matr = malloc(sizeof(*matr) * n); // указатели на n строк
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  matr[i] = malloc(sizeof(float) * n);
```

с последующим обращением к элементам

```
matr[i][j] // i-я строка, j-ый столбец
```

или

```
*(*(matr + i) + j)
```